# Firebird foreign key reference target does not exist null value

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to add a foreign key to my table in Firebird (using IB Expert) using this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk
        FOREIGN KEY (field1) REFERENCES table2(field1)
                ON DELETE SET NULL
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
        USING INDEX fk
```

But I get this weird error:

> Violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk" on table "table1".
> Foreign key reference target does not exist.
> Problematic key value is ("field1" = NULL)

There are no values in `table1` for `field1` which don't exist in `table2`, e.g. this query returns no rows:

```
select * 
from table1 
where field1 not in (select field1 from table2)
```

`field1` is an integer column and the primary key on `table2`.

Even if there existed null values for `field1` in `table1`, this should not be a violation of the foreign key constraint.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The _"Problematic key value is ("field1" = NULL)"_ suggests the problem is with a `field1` with value `NULL`, but those are not checked for foreign keys. Which Firebird version are you using, and can you provide a [mre] (including `CREATE TABLE` DDL, inserts, etc.) to reproduce this?

Comment: `where field1 not in ` - notice this query is useless when you wonder about `NULL` values !!! Read SQL tutorials, `NULL` is a very special value that is excluded from most of the expressions!!!  https://dbfiddle.uk/WGhdkmOY  // also `not in (select` would be extremely slow on Interbase/Firebird , you have to do `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead and check the seocnd table's columns for NULL

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 
I use Firebird 2.5

I don't seem to be able to reproduce it on demand with new/other tables.
The issue also happens when I delete all data from table1

Comment: @HHIED What happens if you backup and restore the database (do it as a separate database), does the problem still occur then in that new DB? Does `gfix -validate -full <your-database>` report anything?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel restoring the database to a new database did not encounter the same issue.
Stopping and starting the Firebird SQL Server seems to have fixed the issue, thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear. If you're not already on it, make sure you use the latest 2.5 (2.5.9). If you get it again, you may want to consider upgrading to 4.0.x.